# Strange problem with SEAM stateful session bean

Tags: seam, richfaces, ejb, stateful, seam2

I've got a stateful session bean.

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("chuckNorrisBean")
public class ChuckNorrisBean implements Serializable, ChuckNorris
```

with some function

```
public void roundHouseKick()
{
    ...
}
```

interface

```
@Local
public interface ChuckNorris
{
    public void roundHouseKick()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and calling them on a jsf .xhtml page using

```
#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick}
```

which works perfectly fine. However if I add the @Stateful annotation to the bean so it becomes

```
@Stateful
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("chuckNorrisBean")
public class ChuckNorrisBean implements Serializable, ChuckNorris
```

and the page will load with exceptions complainig about

```
Exception during request processing:Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException 
with message: "#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: 
//localhost/universe/earth.xhtml @41,65 action=
"#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick}": Method not found: 
ChuckNorrisBean:a6gkg-w6das4-g8wmgh0y-1-g8woy0wo-4b.roundHouseKick()"
```

Any advice on what might've went wrong with my chuckNorrisBean?

The system is built on SEAM/richfaces.

Thanks!

---- Edited to add more info ----

The project is built with maven 2.1 packaged as ear (a single .ear file as target output).

The application server is JBoss.

After more debugging and fiddling, putting

```
<page view-id="/index.xhtml">
    <action execute="#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick}" />
</page>
```

in pages.xml seems to do the kicking just fine. I still couldn't figure out why calling it on a page did not work.

Comment: @John Just for curiosity: is it an war project ??? keep this in mind: @Stateful just work when you have either an EJB project or EAR project. It **does not work** when you have an war project

Comment: I've added info on the build environment too, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Jonh @Statul is better designed to work with ScopeType.CONVERSATION. Its default scope is ScopeType.CONVERSATION. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453746/jboss-seam-enabling-debug-page-on-weblogic-10-3-2-11g/2459795#2459795 **how your app should looks like**. Be aware some settings **can be needed** based on The target app server.

Comment: @Jonh Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631209/what-lift-do-i-gain-from-using-ejb3-in-my-seam-project/2634062#2634062 EAR project does not support HOT-DEPLOYMENT of code

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: I wouldn't say the preferred scope for @Stateful is conversation. Actually it is in fact SESSION. That is why it is often shortened to SFSB (Stateful Session Bean) and SLSB (Stateless Session Bean)

Comment: @Shervin Thank you for your reply but default scope of @Stateful session bean is ScopeType.CONVERSATION. See here: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e3792 It does not make sense to use a @Stateful session bean with ScopeType.SESSION

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: Yes you are right that default scope is Conversation, but that doesn't mean that it is better designed for CONVERSATION. On the contrary, @Stateful is a EJB scope. And when EJB was designed, it was meant for session scope. It is seam that introduced conversation scope as I sure you are well aware of.

For instance, the well known shop cart example is a good example to demonstrate session scope. The cart lives as long as the session of the logged in user is alive. Conversation scope is meant to be a smaller scope, thus have less timeout than session scope.

Comment: But in all fairness, the scope has nothing to say about the question. It should have worked regardless of conversation or session scope.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite strange.

Have you tried

```
#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick()}
```

instead of

```
#{chuckNorrisBean.roundHouseKick}
```

Just to see what happens

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: I cannot explain this. Your code should work.
What I recommend (if you really want a stateful component) is to create a normal Session bean. 
Just remove the @Stateful (and the interface) and try that.

Comment: Which app server are you using?

Comment: What happens if you put `@Statless` instead of `@Stateful`.
Remember, to remove session scope. 

If this doesn't work, then it must be that EJB's isn't available or correctly working for your environment.